# JavaScript function +/-

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to have the other inputs to "+ and -" 60 and 120mm in my function. How do I do it, without make all of them a function?

```
<template>
  <card class="card">
    <h2>Murmål</h2>
    <form>
      <div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <base-input type="number" label="Indtast mål:" v-model="maal"></base-input>
          <base-input type="text" label="Pillemål - 120mm" v-model="pillemaal"></base-input>
          <base-input type="text" label="Pillemål - 60mm" v-model="pillemaal"></base-input>
          <base-input type="text" label="Pillemaal:" v-model="pillemaal"></base-input>
          <base-input type="text" label="Pillemaal + 60mm" v-model="pillemaal"></base-input>
          <base-input type="text" label="Pillemaal + 120mm" v-model="pillemaal"></base-input>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </card>
</template>
<script>
import Card from "./Card.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    Card
  },
  data() {
    return {
      maal: "",
      fuge: 10
      sten: 60
    };
  },
  computed: {
    pillemaal: function() {
      var antal = this.maal / 60;
      return Math.round(antal) * 60 - this.fuge;
      }
  }
};
</script>
<style></style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put the expression in a v-bind like this

```
v-bind:value="pillemaal - 120"
or
:value="pillemaal - 120"
```

v-model wont work because you can't two way bind with an expression.